# Interacting with redux-toolkit from Flutter wrapper

Tags: node.js, reactjs, flutter, react-redux, flutter-inappwebview

I'm working on an app and we have a website with a React frontend and a Flutter wrapper in order to be able to view in an app on mobile (IOS/Android)

We're using the library [Flutter WebView Plugin](https://pub.dev/documentation/flutter_webview_plugin_pro/latest/) for the wrapper. We're using the `flutterWebviewPlugin.evalJavaScript()` function in order to pass some permission  information from the phone to the website and based on that information, I need to be able to update the redux state. While I can display an alert with the data from mobile, I can't seem to pass pass it to the redux state. I'm thinking that some the code is being ran by injection that the references to the store/dispatch may not exist?

I don't have the exact flutter code, but it's something like what is shown in the link

```
Future<String> loadJS(String name) async {
  var givenJS = rootBundle.loadString('assets/$name.js');
  return givenJS.then((String js) {
    flutterWebViewPlugin.onStateChanged.listen((viewState) async {
      if (viewState.type == WebViewState.finishLoad) {
        flutterWebViewPlugin.evalJavascript(js);
      }
    });
  });
}
```

Here is the code that receives the message from flutter

```
// Tried line imports... see below
// import store from "../store";
// import { flutterTest } from "slices/location";

function fromFlutter(data) {
   //Tried to see if inline imports would help
   const store = await import('../store');
   const {flutterTest} = await import('slices/location')

   // Works
   alert(JSON.stringify(data))

   // Doesn't work
   store.dispatch(flutterTest(data))
}
```

Here is the reducer for redux-toolkit (just alerts the message)

```
flutterTest: (state, {payload}) => {
      alert("flutter test 5 ran")
      alert(JSON.stringify(payload))
    }
```

Basically, my question is how do I interact with my React redux state from the Flutter wrapper?

Thanks for your help, everyone!